# FPDF Saving file in a folder on the server QNAP(NAS)?

Tags: php, directory, save, fpdf

Hi guys I have a script in FPDF and PHP to create and save a PDF document. The script is not working (I guess the way I save the path is wrong).
I'd like the user to click save and the document must be saved on a folder inside the server that is hosting the website (in this case is a QNAP). This is the script:

```
<?php
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$sicep = $_SESSION['sicep'];
$notesicep = $_SESSION['notesicep'];

require ('fpdf/fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',11);

$pdf->Cell(100, 8, 'Operatore Centrale Operativa: '.$user, 1 ,1);
$pdf->Cell(100, 8, 'Effettuato in data: ' .date("d/m/Y"). ' In ora: '.date("h:ia") , 1 ,1);
$pdf->Cell(180, 10, 'Verifica funzionale sistema SICEP MVS NET:',1,1);
$pdf->Cell(180, 10, $sicep,1,1);
$pdf->Cell(180, 10, 'Note: '.$notesicep,1,1);
$filename = "orario".date("d/m/Y")."-".date("h:ia").".pdf";
$dir = "/Web/PDF";
$pdf->Output($dir.$filename);
?>
```

The script location is:

> \\192.168.1x.x\Web\Verifiche

And the PDF files should be save in this location:

> \\192.168.1x.x\Web\PDF

How can I do it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to reformulate your question as a _question_, i.e. something like: "I expected foo from the script to happen, but instead bar is happening. Why is this? I also tried changing line 3 from baz to zot but it gave me an error about "Error in input at position 12345" - i.e., make it clear _what you are asking_ and _why your current script does not work_. This will make it much easier for people to answer your question in a good way. Thanks and once again, welcome to the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [FPDF documentation](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm), you have to use the F as parameter to the output function to save the PDF on you local server:

```
$pdf->Output('F','/path/filename.pdf');
```

Comment: can I do it like this?
Output ('F', '/path/$filename'); 
Because I need the file to be saved with a specific name that include date and time

Comment: You need to specify the path + the filename, `'/path/filename.pdf'`is just an example.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, I need to do something like this:
$filename = "orario".date("d/m/Y")."-".date("h:ia").".pdf";
$pdf->Output('F', '/Web/PDF/'.$filename);

Comment: Is not working but I guess the path is wrong. I'm just using this path "/Web/PDF/" and everything is hosted on a QNAP at this location "\\192.168.1x.x\web\PDF". But even using this path won't work "/192.168.1x.x/web/PDF/" even without the var as the file name. The fact that is a QNAP (NAS) might have something to do with it?

Comment: Try the relative path `../PDF/filename.pdf`

Comment: With the '../PDF/something.pdf' is working just fine, but if I try to do it like this it won't work: '../PDF/'.$filename. Guess a var in the filename is not accepted?

Comment: Its because of the format of your `date`, you can't use `:` and `/` in the file name

Comment: Are you sure about that? Because If I try to save it on my local machine using that file name and using the D function, the file name works just fine. Probably it's because after the path '../PDF/name'.date it count the ' after name as a closing tag

Comment: Oh nevermind it worked, I was looking in the wrong folder. Thanks!